# Use filtered rows only for loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Basically I've got some code below that works fine, it's just I'd like it to work on filtered data only- as when it runs from "Allsites" aka the mastersheet whilst filtered it still uses all the data. I'm just wondering if there is anyway to run the code on the filtered data only?

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet

Worksheets("SHLAA").Activate
Worksheets("SHLAA").Select


Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Allsites") 'sheet from workbook im in
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHLAA") 'sheet in workbook im copying too



lngLastRow = Slave.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)

For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
    If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 8).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if ID cell is blank jump to last line
    If Master.Cells(j, 3).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 8).Value Then
            Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value = "31/03/2015"
            Slave.Cells(i, 5).Value = Master.Cells(j, 8).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Planning Permission"
            Slave.Cells(i, 8).Value = Master.Cells(j, 3).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 17).Value = Master.Cells(j, 9).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 24).Value = "1"
            Slave.Cells(i, 27).Value = Master.Cells(j, 15).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 30).Value = Master.Cells(j, 16).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 31).Value = Master.Cells(j, 17).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 48).Value = "Housing only"
            Slave.Cells(i, 52).Value = "MBC"
            Slave.Cells(i, 61).Value = "Manual"
            Slave.Cells(i, 62).Value = Master.Cells(j, 29).Value
            Slave.Cells(i, 63).Value = "0"
            Slave.Cells(i, 64).Value = "Y"
            Slave.Cells(i, 65).Value = "Yes"

    End If

Next

Next

MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")
```

Comment: Basically: `For each cell in master.range("h2:h1000").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)`

Comment: I've tried something similar to this but it seems to crash my code, it just inputs one value in to every cell? Where should i be inserting this, at the moment i've tried after the `For i = 1 to 1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)
```

with this:

```
For each cell in master.range("h2:h1000").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
j = cell.row
```

and add

```
Dim cell as Range
```

to the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the filtered rows by checking RowHeight property (0 or not):

```
If Master.Cells(j, 3).RowHeight = 0 Then
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub noName()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim fpath As String
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
    Dim Slave As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Worksheets("SHLAA").Activate
    Worksheets("SHLAA").Select

    Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Allsites") 'sheet from workbook im in
    Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHLAA") 'sheet in workbook im copying too

    lngLastRow = Slave.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)
        For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
            If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 8).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For
            With Slave
                If Master.Cells(j, 3).RowHeight = 0 Then
                    If Master.Cells(j, 3).Value = .Cells(i, 8).Value Then
                        .Cells(i, 4).Value = "31/03/2015"
                        .Cells(i, 5).Value = Master.Cells(j, 8).Value
                        .Cells(i, 7).Value = "Planning Permission"
                        .Cells(i, 8).Value = Master.Cells(j, 3).Value
                        .Cells(i, 17).Value = Master.Cells(j, 9).Value
                        .Cells(i, 24).Value = "1"
                        .Cells(i, 27).Value = Master.Cells(j, 15).Value
                        .Cells(i, 30).Value = Master.Cells(j, 16).Value
                        .Cells(i, 31).Value = Master.Cells(j, 17).Value
                        .Cells(i, 48).Value = "Housing only"
                        .Cells(i, 52).Value = "MBC"
                        .Cells(i, 61).Value = "Manual"
                        .Cells(i, 62).Value = Master.Cells(j, 29).Value
                        .Cells(i, 63).Value = "0"
                        .Cells(i, 64).Value = "Y"
                        .Cells(i, 65).Value = "Yes"
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")
End Sub
```